# Philodendron Imperial Red: What could be causing "burn spots" on leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, aroid, philodendron

I have been slowly watching spots appear on the new leaves of my philodendron.

They are small, brown and dry (similar in look to leaf tips when under/over watered). They don't appear on the leaves that the plant had when I originally bought it.[image]
[image]
I keep the plant in a window (maybe too bright? I have since pulled it away from my the window sill) and water it when the top layer of soil is dry to the touch (about a 1/2" down). It is planted in a mixture of soil and mulch, with very good drainage.
[image]

I've done a bit of internet searching, (and am now petrified that it's a bacterial issue) but I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this! Has anyone had a similar problem? (am I just a helicopter plant-mom?)

Thank you!

Comment: Not at all a Rhododendron, grins!  It is a Dieffenbachia.  Common name is Dumb Cane.  Ummm, I think, I am pretty sure otherwise this guy is a novelty to me.https://www.epicgardening.com/dieffenbachia-dumb-cane-plant/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a fungal or bacterial problem but an insect infestation. I suspect your plant has spider mite - the little dots in the leaves suggest that, and under magnification, I think I can see what looks like some fine webbing down on the lower stems of the plant, together with some white dots that might be mites. Check with a magnifying glass to make sure that's what I'm seeing - if it's spider mite, a horticultural oil spray or Neem spray should be helpful. For more: [Philodendron Plant Care](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/philodendron-plant-care-69601.html).